# How can I access my ubuntu server installed on my laptop from another linux OS

Tags: server, ssh, 22.04

I've a laptop sitting idle in my home. So, I installed Ubuntu server - 22.04 on that laptop and my aim is to access that server remotely wherever I go from my Linux Mint machine. Not sure how to configure my Ubuntu server so that I can access remotely. Anything is fine with me. I know SSH is one of the way to do it. Not sure how to do it SSH. So, I'm looking for steps.

Answer (score -1):

Edit : Not working: This only if i want to access via Ethernet :(( ...I want via internet

I've **figured out myself** .. Following steps I've followed

**on my server**

1. sudo apt-get install openssh-server
2. sudo service ssh start
3. ip addr show (i got some 192.XXXX.xx)
4. sudo ufw allow 22 #firewall config
5. sudo ufw enable

**on my Linux machine**

1. ssh server_username@192.xxx.xx(IP from server)
2. It asked me password

Boom I'm in!!!!

Comment: Ubuntu Server already includes `openssh-server`. Step 1 should not be necessary.

Comment: In this case, "remotely" means "on the same LAN." Several more steps are needed for secure connections across the internet.

Comment: Not sure @user535733 that's why i've reached community .... So i can't access my server remotly??/ Let me check

Comment: Yupppp can't :( ...Can u pls share me steps/reference? pleaseee

Comment: @user535733 Yeah it's more complex then I think ...Looks like I need DDNS, Static IP(which I've to buy) and I've port forward external traffic on a specific port (e.g., 22 for SSH)from router when I want to access my server over internet ...Wow

Comment: If you have DDNS then you do not need static IP.

Comment: You should use ssh keys. see ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id. After that, disable ssh password login.

Comment: Some more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2466439

Comment: You ***should not*** be behind CGNAT ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT ) also.

Comment: The point of DDNS is to eliminate the need a static IP. DDNS clients are included many consumer-grade routers. Before going down that path, replace your password-based authentication with key-based authentication first.

Comment: That makes sense @user535733